# Defining a function, how to insert "variable paramaters/argument" if first parameter/argument is an error

Tags: javascript

I've been reading [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/), which states:

> With callbacks the most popular way to handle errors is the Node.js style where the first argument to the callback is always reserved for an error.

and gives this example:

```
 var fs = require('fs')

 fs.readFile('/Does/not/exist', handleFile)

 function handleFile (error, file) {
   if (error) return console.error('Uhoh, there was an error', error)
   // otherwise, continue on and use `file` in your code
 }
```

My functions look differenty, something like ths

```
function example (varA, varB){
    //...
    try{
       //...
    }catch {
       //...
    }
}
```

where varA and varB are variables/arguments used to do stuff inside the function. Now, if I would change the code to `function example (error, varA, varB)`, how would I pass the variables, since the first expected argument is actually an error.

If anyone can please provide an example or/and provide some good reading it would be most welcome.

Thank you

Comment: You want to use `example` as a callback to an async function which uses the `(error, data)` paradigm? Well, don't do it directly. Pass a callback to that async function which treats the error case correctly, *and then calls `example(data, ...)` in case of success.*

Comment: pass in `null` or something for `error`? Although, I'm not even sure why you'd want to use the "error-first" approach, especially since the most typical usage is when it's error first, then a single argument for the data. If you are to make this function - where would you use it which fits in with other error-first handlers? And why not use promises?

Comment: didn't think of using null as an argument. Thank you.

Comment: This pattern is used to do some asynchronous work and when done propagate the result (or an error) to some other piece of code. Basically the same job that Promises do nowadays. Many "old" libraries that used that callback pattern are switching to Promises. check the term "promisify".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, if I would change the code to function example (error, varA, varB), how would I pass the variables...

I'm assuming you mean that you're writing an API that will accept callback functions with that kind of signature. If so, on success you call it with `null` as the first parameter, as that's the convention in these callback-style APIs. (And on failure you'e call it with an error as the first parameter, and typically no other parameters.)

```js
// Your API function
function doSomething(param, callback) {
    // There's no point to this style unless the work is asynchronous, so:
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (param.includes("good")) {
            // Success
            callback(null, 1, 2);
        } else {
            // Error
            callback(new Error(`Using param ${param} failed`));
        }
    }, 100);
}

// The callback we'll use
const fn = (error, x, y) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}`);
    }
};

// Example of successful call:
doSomething("good", fn);

// Example of unsuccessful call:
doSomething("bad", fn);
```

But asynchronous callback-style APIs of this kind are obsolete. Instead, use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), directly or indirectly via [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```js
// Your API function
function doSomething(param, callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (param.includes("good")) {
                // Success
                resolve([1, 2]);
            } else {
                // Error
                reject(new Error(`Using param ${param} failed`));
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}

// The fulfillment and rejection callbacks we'll use
const onFulfilled = ([x, y]) => {
    console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}`);
};
const onRejected = (reason) => {
    console.error(reason);
};

// Example of successful call:
doSomething("good").then(onFulfilled, onRejected);

// Example of unsuccessful call:
doSomething("bad").then(onFulfilled, onRejected);

// Examples in an `async` function instead of `onFulfilled`/`onRejected`
async function usingApi(param) {
    try {
        const [x, y] = await doSomething(param);
        console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
setTimeout(() => { // Just so we know the earlier examples have finished
    usingApi("good").then(() => usingApi("bad"));
}, 400);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the examples. makes more sense now,

Answer (score 1):

It depends of what you want.

1. Someone calls your function.  You function can return sync result - error is not needed here. (callback context). If your function is async, then you request cb function as last argument

```
function example (varA, varB, cb){
    //...
    try{
       cb(null, varA+varB)
    }catch (e) {
       cb(e, null)
    }
}
```

In that case you pass the err to the calling code, cuz it is common contract.

> With callbacks the most popular way to handle errors is the Node.js style where the first argument to the callback is always reserved for an error.

```
example(1, 2, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {}
  else {
    result is valid
  }
})
```

2. Function from our example is just regular function => there are not necessary to work with err arg. Just return return as usual.

Callback uses for async operations. These operation can be finished with error and first err argument is a common way to say you "we have a problem"